# Can I specify the character encoding when writing to an Excel file using Excellink?

Tags: excel, character-encoding

I'm working with a file with UTF-8 encoding, and there are several non-ASCII characters in names and addresses.  After writing data to an Excel file using ExcelWrite, some non-ASCII characters are incorrect, e.g. this character "ö" appears as "ã\n" (with a newline after it). Can I specify the character encoding when writing to an Excel file using Excellink?

Comment: Can you give an example of the text that produces these errors?